# jQuery radio button check add class, else remove class if radio button not checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need 2 radio button

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  if ($('#user_personal').is(':checked')) {
    $('.user_company').addClass('hidden');
    $('.user_personal').removeClass('hidden');
  } else if ($('#user_company').is(':checked')) {
    $('.user_personal').addClass('hidden');
    $('.user_company').removeClass('hidden');
  }

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-type-item">
  <input name="user" id="user_personal" type="radio">
</div>
<div class="user-type-item">
  <input name="user" id="user_company" type="radio">
</div>

<div class="user_personal">
  <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
    <option value="0"></option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="user_company">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Now I have to use Jquery to check the radio "#user_personal", "div.user_company" add the "hidden" class and "div.user_personal" remove the "hidden" class.
And when I check on the radio "#user_company", "div.user_personal" add the "hidden" class and "div.user_company" removes the "hidden" class.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you attempted anything at all?

Comment: this looks like a homework?

Comment: I'm not sure about jQuery, looking forward to the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `toggleClass` to toggle displays between the select and the input

```js
$('.user-type-item input').click(function(){
     $('.user_personal,.user_company').toggleClass('hidden');

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-type-item">
  <input name="user" id="user_personal" type="radio" checked>
</div>
<div class="user-type-item">
  <input name="user" id="user_company" type="radio">
</div>

<div class="user_personal hidden">
  <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
                     <option value="0">選択してください。</option>
               </select>
</div>

<div class="user_company">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

multiple elements:

```js
$('.user-type-item input').click(function() {
  var ind = $(this).parent().index();
  $('.el').addClass('hidden');//hide all inputs
  $('.el').eq(ind).toggleClass('hidden');//show only the input coresponding to the checked radio

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="user-type-item">
  <input name="user" id="user_personal" type="radio" checked>
</div>
<div class="user-type-item">
  <input name="user" id="user_company" type="radio">
</div>
<div class="user-type-item">
  <input name="user" id="user_company" type="radio">
</div>
</div>
<div class="el user_personal">
  <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
                     <option value="0">選択してください。</option>
               </select>
</div>

<div class="el user_company hidden">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="el user_company hidden">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if I have 3 radio buttons and 3 divs?

Comment: the same principle applies you hide all the inputs and show only the current one